# xaml styles Is there a way to specify fontsize to one of 5 values?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I would like to be able to support 5 sizes,
verysmall, small, normal, large, verylarge.

is there a smart way to do that with styles?
< fontsize={DynamicResourec Small}"/>

where I define small somewhere else?

- I am aware that i could just write 18, insstead, but I might want to scale the fonts later...

Comment: Yes, in your resources and name it x:Key="Small".

Comment: ok, that makes sense, but How do I add an int with the name small... probably very simple

Comment: FontSize is of type System.Double:  `<system:Double x:Key="Small" >18</system:Double>`

Comment: If you add that to Application.Resouces it will available in your whole app

Comment: I have moved it all to a resource assembly, but the System.Double couses problems.
Could i be because I use .NET 5?

Comment: What kind of problems? System.Double exists in .Net 5 as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=net-5.0

Comment: The <System.Double... shows up in red, propably due to some wrong includes..
ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete example with .Net 5 where the resource is in MainWindow.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfNet5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfNet5"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <system:Double x:Key="VerySmall">12</system:Double>
    <system:Double x:Key="Small">18</system:Double>
    <system:Double x:Key="Medium">22</system:Double>
    <system:Double x:Key="Large">26</system:Double>
</Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
      <StackPanel >
          <TextBlock Text="Very small" FontSize="{DynamicResource VerySmall}"/>
          <TextBlock Text="Small" FontSize="{DynamicResource Small}"/>
          <TextBlock Text="Medium" FontSize="{DynamicResource Medium}"/>
          <TextBlock Text="Large" FontSize="{DynamicResource Large}"/>
      </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

How it looks in run-time:
[image]

Comment: Thanks,. that was exactly what I was looking for, and my trouble was, very simpl.
I wrote <System.Double .... thanks ;-)